# CodeceptJS and Nightmare - set cookie before suite in helper class

Tags: nightmare, codeceptjs

I decided use framework CodeceptJS and library Nightmare.

Mine issue is set cookie before run all test suite
I read the documentation and understanding so for that to solve mine issue me need use helper classes. Maybe I'm wrong but still.
Perhaps you need to use a different approach if so let me know.

It mine helper

```
'use strict';

class SetCookie extends Helper {

  constructor(config){
    super(config)
  }

  _beforeSuite() {
    this.client = this.helpers['Nightmare'].browser;

    this.getCookies().then((cookies) => {
      console.log(cookies);
    })
  }

getCookies(){
  return this.client.cookies.get()
  }
}

module.exports = SetCookie;
```

**Problem**
Cookies return after finished test suite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem:
Mine Helper

```
    async setSplitCookies() {
        const client = this.helpers['Nightmare'];

        const cookie = {
          name: 'rc_web_spl', 
          value: 'on',
          url: 'http://www.nic.ru'
        }
        return client.setCookie(cookie);
}
```

Mine test:

```
Before((I) => {
    I.setSplitCookies();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

https://codecept.io/helpers/Nightmare/#setcookie
That is existing nightmare helper. Did you try it?